# How do I delete folders using regex from Linux terminal

Tags: regex, linux, find, rm

Say I have folders:

```
img1/
img2/
```

How do I delete those folders using regex from Linux terminal, that matches everything starts with img?

Comment: For the record, the shell's glob wildcard expressions are not proper regular expressions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use find to filter directories

```
$ find . -type d -name "img*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

As it was mentioned in a comments this is using shell globs not regexs. If you want regex

```
$ find . -type d -regex "\./img.*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: one way to improve this could consist in adding `-maxdepth 1` to `find` like that `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -regex "\./img.*" -exec rm -rf {} \;` it will be faster.

Comment: I used your command quite a lot to clean the old backups on our production servers, but I can't figure out a regex to get all folders except the first of the month (means I want to wipe out every backup folder except 1 for each month). The folders name are defined like this: "yyyy.mm.dd.hh.MM.ss" (ex: 2016.07.29.03.00.19). Even `find . -type d -regex "\./2016\.*"` does not return anything ... any idea?

Comment: try `find . -type d -regex ".*/2016.*"`

Comment: `{}` is replaced by the file name and `\;` marks the end of the command passed to exec (if you don't escape it it would be taken by the shell)

Comment: [Other discussions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245287/184553) also mention `$ find . -type d -regex "^\./img.*$" -exec rm -rf {} +`

Answer (score 20):

you could use

```
rm -r img*
```

that should delete all files and directories in the current working directory starting with img

EDIT:

to remove only directories in the current working directory starting with img

```
rm -r img*/
```

Comment: this will also delete any file that will match the expression, this command delete everything that match the expression, not only directories.

Comment: the OP says 'that matches everything starts with img?'

Comment: If name must start img you should use `^img.*`. Without `^` character name may have img for example on the middle.

Comment: as my solution was not using full regex just shell glob wildcard, as mentioned in other comment, that doesnt happen in this case

Answer (score 2):

In the process of looking for how to use regexps to delete specific files inside a directory I stumbled across this post and another one by Mahmoud Mustafa: http://mah.moud.info/delete-files-or-directories-linux

This code will delete anything including four consecutive digits in 0-9, in my case folders with months and dates ranging from Jan2002 - Jan2014:

```
rm -fr `ls | grep -E [0-9]{4}`
```

Hope that helps anyone out there looking around for how to delete individual files instead of folders.